# how to add a separator in in xtext list?

Tags: eclipse, grammar, dsl, xtext

I have the following grammar fragment:

```
FixtureGroup:
                            name            = ID 
    ':'                     fixtures += [Fixture]*
    ';';
```

And in the instance I can type for the above rule the following:

```
FrontLeft: FrontLeft1 FrontLeft2;
```

However, what I like to type is a plus in between:

```
FrontLeft: FrontLeft1 + FrontLeft2;
```

How should I change the grammar to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the ususal pattern is

```
':' (fixtures += [Fixture] ('+' fixtures += [Fixture])*)?
```