# How to refer to a property reference instead of a 'named' reference?

Tags: eclipse, grammar, dsl, xtext

This question is a follow up on [/how-to-add-a-separate-in-in-xtext-list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55929123/how-to-add-a-separate-in-in-xtext-list).

I have the following grammar part:

```
 Fixture:
                            name            = ID
    ('('                    abbreviation    = ID ')')?
    ':'                     type            = FixtureType 
    'startDmxChannel' '='   startDmxChannel = INT
    ';';

FixtureGroup:
                            name            = ID 
    ('('                    abbreviation    = ID ')')?
    ':'                     fixtures += [Fixture.abbreviation]*
    ';';
```

And I have in the instance the following part:

```
Fixtures
{
    FrontRight1  (FR1) : FunPar startDmxChannel=1;
    FrontRight2  (FR2) : FunPar startDmxChannel=9;
    FrontRight3  (FR3) : FunPar startDmxChannel=17;
    FrontRight4  (FR4) : FunPar startDmxChannel=25;
}

FixtureGroups
{
    FrontRight: FrontRight1 FrontRight2 FrontRight3 FrontRight4;
```

I would like to use the abbreviation names in the last line instead:

```
    FrontRight: FR1 FR2 FR3 FR4;
```

Or even better, a combination of name or abbreviation like:

```
    FrontRight: FrontRight1 FR2 FR3 FR4;
```

How to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 things involved here

- For global references (between file): Customizing `IDefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy` (by subclassing `DefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy`) allows to index elements under multiple names and adding information to userdata e.g. if index name is an abbreviation
- for local references the same can be done at `org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.impl.ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.internalGetAllDescriptions(Resource)`
- you can then adapt the `MyDslScopeProvider` to filter for correct refs.
- if the references are local anyway you can do everything in your `MyDslScopeProvider`

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the good direction; I accepted the answer but will try it later.